# how to use trigger add column value while relate table insert record?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I created the following PostgreSQL function and the corresponding trigger. I want to insert data into the user_star_raider table, the stars column data in the raider table can automatically increase by 1, but now I use the current function and trigger and it does not meet expectations The result, can you help me?

raider table:

```
 raider_id | stars | visits
-----------+-------+--------
 13243     |     0 |   4525
```

user_star:

```
 user_id | raider_id | star_date
---------+-----------+-----------
```

I create function and trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auto_increase_star() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE raider SET stars = stars + 1 WHERE raider.raider_id = new.raider_id;
        RETURN new;
    end
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER add_user_star_raider_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON user_star_raider FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE auto_increase_star();
```

When I insert a row `('1900327840@qq.com', '13243', '2020-07-25')` to `use_star_raider`, I want the raider stars column to be increased by 1.

Is there any good solution?

Comment: I think you may be missing both the "PL/pgSQL" and a "postgresql" tags. Also, please post the definition for your "user_star_raider" table, unless the "user_star:" is a typo and you accidentally just missed the "_raider" part. Note that "does not meet expectations" is too vague. What happens when you try this?

Comment: The trigger looks correct, what is the error you get?

Comment: Your code works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=48e9941617b7fc3149725c284f002206.

Comment: It has been working normally. After I modified the auto_increase_star() function, I used an update operation on the raider before inserting the record, so it did not work normally.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, your code works.  Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=48e9941617b7fc3149725c284f002206).

I realize that I made one change in the db<>fiddle to facilitate typing -- and that might be the cause of your problem.  I changed the `raider_id` from a string to a number:  fewer pesky quotes to deal with.

That, in turn, means that the values necessarily match; integers have the nice property that what you see is what you get.  However, with strings, strange things can happen -- such as hidden characters or look-alikes from different character sets.  What may be happening is that everything works, but the `raider_id` values don't match between the tables.  My advice is to set up a foreign key relationship, to be sure that the `raider_id` in the second table is a valid `raider_id` based on the first table.